# LoadLibrary on jvm.dll fails with error code 183

Tags: c++, jvm, loadlibrary

I'm trying to use JNI in C++ to call a method from Java.

I have tried this on a console application and it worked, but when I switch to a DLL that is loaded in any application, it fails with error "ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS"

```cpp
    HMODULE jvmDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_191\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");
    if (!jvmDLL) {
        int error = GetLastError(); // this returns 183
    }
```

This works perfectly fine on anything but a DLL injected into any application. It shouldn't be null.

Comment: I tried `LoadLibraryEx(jvmDLLPath, NULL, LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL)` and it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
HMODULE jvmDLL = LoadLibrary("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_191\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");
if (!jvmDLL)
   jvmDLL = GetModuleHandle("jvm.dll");
}
```